# Vba code to get table from webpage to excel

Tags: vba, msxml

I am trying to get table from webpage to excel but no result and also i am not getting any error message.Below is the code which i have try.

```html
Sub Web_Table_Option_One()
Dim xml    As Object
Dim html   As Object
Dim objTable As Object
Dim result As String
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lngTable As Long
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngCol As Long
Dim ActRw As Long
Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
With xml
.Open "GET", "https://www.99acres.com/microsite/ambey-group-eco-valley-new-town-kolkata-east/", False
.Send
End With
result = xml.responseText
Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
html.body.innerHTML = result
Set objTable = html.getElementsByTagName("table")
 For lngTable = 0 To objTable.Length - 1
        For lngRow = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length - 1
            For lngCol = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells.Length - 1
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(ActRw + lngRow + 1, lngCol + 1) = objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).innerText
            Next lngCol
        Next lngRow
        ActRw = ActRw + objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length + 1
    Next lngTable
End Sub
```

I want to get table as shown in below pic

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get an idea to use `getElementsByTagName("table")`, while there is no single `table` tag on this page? It's all DIVs.

I operate on `HTMLDocument` which requires reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library, `Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")` gave me an object which didn't allow `getElementsByClassName`.

I removed all (now) redundant variable declarations.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Web_Table_Option_One()

    Dim xml As Object
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim myTable As HTMLObjectElement
    Dim result As String
    Dim rowNum As Long
    Dim colNum As Long      

    Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")

    With xml
        .Open "GET", "https://www.99acres.com/microsite/ambey-group-eco-valley-new-town-kolkata-east/", False
        .Send
    End With

    result = xml.responseText

    html.body.innerHTML = result
    Set myTable = html.getElementsByClassName("divTableBody")(0)

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
        For rowNum = 0 To myTable.Children.Length - 1
            For colNum = 0 To myTable.Children(rowNum).Children.Length - 1
                .Cells(rowNum + 1, colNum + 1) = myTable.Children(rowNum).Children(colNum).innerText
            Next colNum
        Next rowNum
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi,Ryszard Jędraszyk & SIM thanks for the reply, your boath macro working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You were after the wrong tag names. However, the below approach can fetch you the tabular data from that page:

```
Sub FetchTable()
    Dim HTTP As New XMLHTTP60, HTML As New HTMLDocument
    Dim trow As HTMLDivElement, tcel As HTMLDivElement, R&, C&

    With HTTP
        .Open "GET", "https://www.99acres.com/microsite/ambey-group-eco-valley-new-town-kolkata-east/", False
        .send
        HTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    For Each trow In HTML.getElementsByClassName("divTableBody")(0).Children
        For Each tcel In trow.getElementsByClassName("divTableCell")
            C = C + 1: Cells(R + 1, C) = tcel.innerText
        Next tcel
        C = 0: R = R + 1
    Next trow
End Sub
```